# How to make an iTunes like (playlists, library) left-sided (collapsible) navigation bar?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I am talking about the navigation area on the left side of iTunes for Library and Playlists. I'm wondering if this is a built in class (which I couldn't find documented) or something custom implemented by Apple.

I'm working an a mac application where I want to include that type of navigation. I want to allow people to "fold" the categories up by using the triangles. Do I need to write a custom implementation of this, or can I use some control in Interface Builder or some open source library?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bar is called a *source list*. In 10.5, you can use an `NSTableView` for this, as described [here](http://chanson.livejournal.com/176310.html). Before 10.5, you'll have to resort to third-party implementations.

See also: ["How would one implement a sidebar similar to Mail/iTunes/Finder/etc in Cocoa/IB?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241507/how-would-one-implement-a-sidebar-similar-to-mail-itunes-finder-etc-in-cocoa-ib)

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `NSOutlineView`, as shown in [this example](http://developer.apple.com/samplecode/SourceView/index.html)